# Why is my View acting like this after disabling scrolling on my Form?

Tags: ios, swiftui

[This](https://imgur.com/a/pt24o6x) is how the view is behaving and I don't know why. The view jerks down every time I switch to it. It happens because of the scrolling being disabled but I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried already to put the `scrollingDisabled` modifier to the `VStack` but it didn't change anything. Mind you I'm kind of beginner with SwiftUI, so please bare with me.

**This is the relevant part of the code**

```swift
ZStack {
    VStack {
        Form {
               Section(header: Text("First name")) {
                   TextField("First name", text: $firstName)
                       .padding(13)
                       .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                       .stroke(.gray))
                       .submitLabel(.done)
               }

               Section(header: Text("Last name")) {
                   TextField("Last name (Optional)", text: $lastName)
                       .padding(13)
                       .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                       .stroke(.gray))
                       .submitLabel(.done)
               }
               .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
               .scrollDisabled(true)
    }
```

**This the entire code of the view**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SignUpNameView: View {
    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""

    @State private var birthDate = Date.now

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("First name")) {
                        TextField("First name", text: $firstName)
                            .padding(13)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                                .stroke(.gray))
                            .submitLabel(.done)
                    }

                    Section(header: Text("Last name")) {
                        TextField("Last name (Optional)", text: $lastName)
                            .padding(13)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                                .stroke(.gray))
                            .submitLabel(.done)
                    }
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .scrollDisabled(true)

                Spacer()

                Button(action : {
                    print("Already")
                }) {
                    Text("Already have an account?")
                        .padding()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(value: SignUpDate()) {
                    Text("Continue")
                        .fontType1()
                }
                .buttonType1(x: 0, y: 0)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: SignUpDate.self) { destination in
            SignUpDateView()
        }
        .toolbarSignUp(currentStep: 1, lastStep: 4)
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It seems like your view is in a `NavigationStack`, but the code you posted does not have a `NavigationStack`. Also, the screenshot shows the view being moved up, not "jerks down". Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I meant the Form is moved down. The view doesn't need to be in a NavigationStack it's not the root view. And I cannot show a minimal reproductible example since the only thing I know why the view is acting as is, is because I added the .scrollDisabled(true) modifier. When I remove it, it works perfectly, when I add it back it does this thing.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that the form is being moved up, overlapping with the safe area though. Also, when I put your view as a non-root view in a `NavigationStack`, the form is not moved up.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, it still moves up even when I put it in a `NavigationStack`. By the way, by moved down I meant what happens in a chronological order and not in reverse chronological order like you meant it.

Comment: I found a temporary solution by adding the `.scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)` modifier to the form. The problem is that the feature is only available from iOS 16.4 and the conversion rate is not as high as I'd like it to be.

Comment: We need more code. You don’t show the `SignUpDateView`, and that’s where the bouncing happens.

Comment: The bouncing happens on every view where the scrolling is disabled. I shared the entire SignUpNameView code where the bouncing also happens exactly the same way as all the other views. There is no difference the problem is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a form seems to shuffle around after being shown, especially if there is any conditional content or conditional layout. It may help to force a rebuild of the form with onAppear:

```swift
    @State private var isDummyContentShowing = true

    var body: some View {
        Form {

            // All the real stuff

            if isDummyContentShowing {
                Text(".")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { isDummyContentShowing = false }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I tried the `.onAppear` method but it still does the same thing. By the way, didn't you mean to put the state variable to false and then change to true inside the `.onAppear` modifier? Because done like this the `Form` is just not gonna show at all.

Comment: Shame it didn't work. I didn't get confused with the state variable though, it's the dummy content that gets hidden in onAppear, not the rest of the form.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't reappear it just gets hidden then. But it doesn't even matter since the jerking down happens during OnAppear. I have linked the state variable to a button though and the form appears perfectly well, so it seems that if I wait for the onAppear state to finish the form will be just fine.